# Converting CSV to nested json objects with arrays in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert csv to json with nested objects and arrays. I am trying to make it dynamic so that if I add fields to csv it updates the json without modifying the converter

Input.csv

```
id,input.a,input.b.x.input.b.y,input.c
1,2,a,b,"3,4"
1,2,c,d,"3,4"
2,3,p,q,"5"
```

Output.json

```
{
  "1":{
    "a": 2,
    "b": [
      {
        "x":a
        "y":b
      },
      {
        "x":c
        "y":d
      }
    ],
    "c" : [3,4]
  },
  
  "2":{
    "a": 3,
    "b": [
      {
        "x":p
        "y":q
      }
    ],
    "c" : [5]
  }
}
```

Comment: Adding some code to create a minimum reproducible example will help you get an answer to this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It looks like you might need to write your own code to do this conversion.

For the 'id', you'll probably want to use a data structure like a dictionary.

Comment: What happens if `c` value is different for a given `id`? Do the values get appended to the array or do you go to nested arrays?

Comment: Input is pretty strict and there won't different values

Comment: And input.c will always be a an array of ints (or numbers), and input.b.* will always be strings?

Answer (score 0):

This solution looks bigger because of all the typing and TypedDicts, which you could remove if you really wanted.

When I run this against your sample input.csv, I get your sample output.json:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import json

from collections.abc import Iterator
from typing import TypedDict

# Build up to the final structure, JSON_Data
class B_Dict(TypedDict):
    x: str
    y: str


class ID_Dict(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: list[B_Dict]
    c: list[int]


JSON_Data = dict[int, ID_Dict]

CSV_Row = list[str]
ID_idx = 0
A_idx = 1
Bx_idx = 2
By_idx = 3
C_idx = 4


def main():
    with open("input.csv", newline="") as f_in, open("output.json", "w") as f_out:
        reader = csv.reader(f_in)

        data = csv_to_json(reader)

        json.dump(data, f_out, indent=4)


def csv_to_json(csv_reader: Iterator[CSV_Row]) -> JSON_Data:
    header = next(csv_reader)
    assert header[ID_idx] == "id"
    assert header[A_idx] == "input.a"
    assert header[Bx_idx] == "input.b.x"
    assert header[By_idx] == "input.b.y"
    assert header[C_idx] == "input.c"

    data: JSON_Data = {}

    for row in csv_reader:
        id_ = int(row[ID_idx])
        a = int(row[A_idx])
        bx = row[Bx_idx]
        by = row[By_idx]
        c = [int(x) for x in row[C_idx].split(",")]

        # Since every row in the CSV is a self-contained ID_Dict, this
        # is the only logic we need: to create the ID_Dict once...
        if id_ not in data:
            data[id_] = ID_Dict(a=a, b=[B_Dict(x=bx, y=by)], c=c)
            continue

        # ...then update it as other rows with the same ID are encountered
        data[id_]["b"].append(B_Dict(x=bx, y=by))

    return data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If you need to add another key/field, like b, that is a list and values are appended for each row, e.g. d:

```
| id | input.a | input.b.x | input.b.y | input.c | input.d.m | input.d.n |
|----|---------|-----------|-----------|---------|-----------|-----------|
| 1  | 2       | a         | b         | 3,4     | 10.0      | 11.1      |
| 1  | 2       | c         | d         | 3,4     | 12.2      | 13.3      |
| 2  | 3       | p         | q         | 5       | 98.8      | 99.9      |
```

add a TypedDict for it, then add that to the ID_Dict:

```py
class D_Dict(TypedDict):
    m: float
    n: float

class ID_Dict(TypedDict):
    a: int
    b: list[B_Dict]
    c: list[int]
    d: list[D_Dict]  # ← add here
```

update your CSV header indexes and asserts:

```py
Dm_idx = 5
Dn_idx = 6

...

assert header[Dm_idx] == "input.d.m"
assert header[Dn_idx] == "input.d.n"
```

and finally:

```py
dm = float(row[Dm_idx])
dn = float(row[Dn_idx])

if id_ not in data:
    data[id_] = ID_Dict(
        a=a,
        b=[B_Dict(x=bx, y=by)],
        c=c,
        d=[D_Dict(m=dm, n=dn)],  # ← add here
    )
    continue

data[id_]["b"].append(B_Dict(x=bx, y=by))
data[id_]["d"].append(D_Dict(m=dm, n=dn))
```